# Speed up PostgreSQL query with complicated JOIN condition

Tags: database, postgresql

We have two PostgreSQL tables A and B.

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    aid          text PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    sessionid    text,
    b_id         text,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE B
(
    bid          text PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    sessionids   text[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'::text[],
    ...
);
```

an index exists:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY index_A_from_B ON A (b_id, sessionid)
```

and there is a one-to-many relation between table B and table A.

Table A is huge, i.e. millions of records and table B can assumed to be a lot smaller (order 10e4 times smaller). The one-to-many relationship is as follows: a record in table A will match with exactly record of table B given the following condition `b_id = bid  OR  sessionid = ANY (sessionids)`.

The referential integrity is guaranteed by the trigger function on table A that actually UPSERTs elements of table B (no records are inserted directly into table B).

### The problem

The question is as follows: how can we speed up a query like this one:

```
WITH 
-- CTE to extract relevant records of table B
relevant_B_part as (
    SELECT bid, sessionids
    FROM B
    WHERE t > date('2017-03-9') -- some conditions, but there is a partial index that speeds up this part
),
-- CTE to extract relevant records of table A
relevant_A_part as (
    SELECT *
    FROM A
    WHERE t > date('2017-02-20')
)
SELECT count(*)
FROM 
    relevant_A_part as rA
INNER JOIN relevant_B_part as rB
ON 
        rA.b_id = rB.bid 
    OR  rA.sessionid = ANY (rB.sessionids)
```

This query essentially takes some records of table B and counts the matching colums of table A (although there can be some extra conditions on table A).

Is there a smart way (index, foreign key, ...) to explain to PostgreSQL how to link these two tables that would speed up our query?

In principle we don't need to execute the JOIN, instead we also tried lateral joins, but till now, all queries we tried kept being horribly slow.

We cannot add columns to table A, but are at liberty when it comes to table B.

Explain Analyzed:

```
Aggregate  (cost=13264593.88..13264593.89 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=151434.540..151434.540 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: count(*)
  Buffers: shared hit=9677 read=9009, temp written=8769
  CTE relevant_b_part
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.b  (cost=25.50..897.81 rows=387 width=118) (actual time=0.104..0.744 rows=227 loops=1)
          Output: b.bid, b.sessionids
          Recheck Cond: (b.t > '2017-03-09'::date)
          Heap Blocks: exact=122
          Buffers: shared hit=127
          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_b_p  (cost=0.00..25.41 rows=387 width=0) (actual time=0.080..0.080 rows=227 loops=1)
                Buffers: shared hit=5
  CTE relevant_a_part
    ->  Seq Scan on public.a  (cost=0.00..38970.65 rows=971199 width=86) (actual time=0.022..803.094 rows=970142 loops=1)
          Output: a.aid, a.sessionid, a.b_id, a.t
          Filter: (a.t > '2017-02-20'::date)
          Rows Removed by Filter: 662790
          Buffers: shared hit=9550 read=9009
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..13174318.31 rows=20162846 width=0) (actual time=130814.665..151433.062 rows=5530 loops=1)
        Join Filter: ((ra.b_id = rb.bid) OR (ra.sessionid = ANY (rb.sessionids)))
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 220216704
        Buffers: shared hit=9677 read=9009, temp written=8769
        ->  CTE Scan on relevant_a_part ra  (cost=0.00..19423.98 rows=971199 width=64) (actual time=0.028..1689.252 rows=970142 loops=1)
              Output: ra.aid, ra.sessionid, ra.b_id, ra.t
              Buffers: shared hit=9550 read=9009, temp written=8769
        ->  CTE Scan on relevant_b_part rb  (cost=0.00..7.74 rows=387 width=64) (actual time=0.000..0.054 rows=227 loops=970142)
              Output: rb.bid, rb.sessionids
              Buffers: shared hit=127
Planning time: 0.268 ms
Execution time: 151438.180 ms
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: The smart way would be to avoid the CTE and replace it by the corresponding (sub) queries. Note: `index_A_from_B ON events (bid, sessionid)` it makes no sense to refer to more than the PK in an FK constraint. The PK is unique enough ...Also: `CREATE TABLE A
{
    aid: text PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, ...`is a syntax error (actually two)

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for the comment. I fixed the syntax error and saw that the there was an underscore missing in the index definition. Note that the index is not defined on a primary key.

Comment: Without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output it is impossible to say anything definite, but often a query like `SELECT ... WHERE a=x OR b=y` can be made faster like this: `SELECT ... WHERE a=x UNION SELECT ... WHERE b=y` (not that the queries are not equivalent if there are duplicate rows).